# Save current state of Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to save current state of **Selenium** browser?

To understand I will provide an example:

Let's say that there is a web page. I clicked on the button where I found many other buttons. I want to check each of those buttons sequentially. The problem is that each of this buttons needs to obtain browsers information like **referrer** which should be the first page after first click etc.

In this case I would need to have those information saved in a browser because if I clicked on the second button the **referrer** would be page which was recently opened. I can't click on a third right after that. I would have to go back, but some web pages does not allow browsers '**back**'. Another advantage is that I would not have to send a new request to the server.

Something like this:

```
for but in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('button'):
    state = driver.save_state()
    but.click()
    # do stuff
    driver.load_state(state)
```

Comment: Does the URL always change when you hit a button in the list? Also, is referrer the only thing causing problems?

Comment: The page is very tough one I think. It does not allows even back button on browser (it not works properly, you can use 'back' but you don't get page where you have been step before). Yes, it changes but URL is not enough at all to get somewhere where you want. It is some kind of dynamic generated stuff.

Comment: I don't think that the referrer is the only thing because you can't get somewhere on this page just passing a correct referrer and URL. It's more complicated. Save_state would be perfect.

Comment: a crazy idea: try copying the browser object. In the loop do `tmp = copy.deepcopy(driver)` then `but.click()` then `driver = tmp`

Comment: Interesting idea, I think that it will works! I'm going to try it, thanks!

Comment: ok, if it does I'll post it as an answer! I cannot try it out myself right now. However, thinking about it... no it shouldn't work as it is, since the `for` iterates on a `driver`'s attribute. The loop should be rewritten.

Comment: @Pynchia Unfortunately, it does not works... copy.Error: un(deep)copyable object of type <type '_subprocess_handle'>

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik did you find an answer to this? i am having the same issue

Comment: You can attempt to copy all the cookies in your browser, then after each action, set the cookies back to how they were before (assuming stuff like the referrer is stored there).  I don't know the python bindings, though, so I can't make any suggestions about the how.  In java you'd be dealing with the `driver.manage().getCookies()` as well as `manage().deleteCookie(cookie)` and `manage().addCookie(cookie)` in order to fetch, add and delete cookies.  Python could be similar maybe.  Typically webdriver doesn't cache browser state like that, so you have to get and sets that state on the browser

Comment: Just did a google search, it sounds like the referrer is a header stored on the http request.  If that's true, then that puts this outside the scope of what selenium is capable of.  What you can do though, is hook up a proxy to your driver instance, which would let you inspect headers of interest in your browser activity, and intercept requests to the browser so you can make modifications to the request headers.  Unless recent versions of selenium made this change, it's always been an intentional decision to not allow webdriver to get at the raw http by the devs.

Comment: I think it's impossible, because when you clicking on buttons the state can change not only on client but also on back-end side, and you can't prevent it.

Comment: Have you tried opening all the buttons in new tabs. And switch tab as necessary.

Comment: Is there an answer to this question? I'm trying to run several tests from a certain "browser state" and want to return to that state after each test without refreshing the page.

Answer (score -1):

There is another solution. The web browser usually uses the cache to save the state of it. Therefore, you can save the cache before clicking each button then reuse the cache to get back to before clicking state.
I already use that solution in my project. It will work perfectly if nothing is saved into database or another third party.

Comment: Example code or at least a link to the relevant documentation/APIs would make this a great answer.